# BooleanFilter with empty FilterClause in Lucene.NET 3.0.3

Tags: lucene.net, lucene-filters

I am using `BooleanFilter` for performing filter in lucene index.

code:

```
BooleanFilter _filter = new BooleanFilter();
var locationFilter = new TermsFilter();
locationFilter.AddTerm(new Term("Location", "Dhaka"));
_filter.Add(new FilterClause(locationFilter, Occur.MUST));
```

And in my Search code snippet

```
 var hits = searcher.Search(query, _filter, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
```

This code works fine;

But sometimes i don't need to filter with location then i just put a empty BooleanFilter and perform search like this:

```
 BooleanFilter _filter = new BooleanFilter();
    var hits = searcher.Search(query, _filter, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
```

Now why do hits not return me no search result?;

Answer (score 1):

I think that your empty `BooleanFilter` is matching nothing..

Try using the other overload of search `search(Query query, int n, Sort sort)`

Comment: I have done it with a checking, `if(not any filter option)` then `search(Query query, int n, BooleanFilter null,Sort sort)`